# ArduinoボードマネージャーのSpresenseのインストールや削除でエラーが出ます。

Tags: spresense, arduino

Arduino1.8.13を使用していますが、ボードマネージャーでSpresenseのバージョン変更や削除ができません。
またボードマネージャーの画面下に赤く「java.langNullPointerException」と表示が出てその先に進みません。
どこに問題があるのでしょうか。
因みに他のファイルのアップデート等は出来ます。

実行した手順は次のような状況です。

1. Spresenseバージョン2.0.1でプログラミング＆書き込みを実行。（正常に動作）
2. Spresenseバージョン2.1.0のアップデートを実施後、プログラミング＆書き込みを実行。（正常に動作）
3. プログラム中にSpresenseバージョンによって動きが違うのではないかと思い、Spresenseバージョン2.0.1にもどす。
4. コンパイル＆書き込みを実行。（動作正常：この時点で、インストールにエラーが出ていたかどうかは不明）
5. 他のバージョンのインストールや、削除を試したが、変わっていない気がしたので、よく見ると画面下に赤く「java.langNullPointerException」と表示が出ていた。
6. 他のアップデートもダメになったか、他のアップデートや元に戻すなどを確認したが、Spresense以外は問題ない。
7. Spresenseのバージョンを確認すると2.1.0が選択できない。（表示に無い）

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

私もArduino IDEを使っていてたまにこの問題に遭遇します。

Arduino15配下の以下のディレクトリに、
複数バージョンのフォルダや空フォルダが存在していたりしないでしょうか？

- Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/
- Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/tools/spresense-sdk/
- Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/tools/spresense-tools/

Arduino15ディレクトリの場所はプラットフォームごとに異なるので以下を参考にしてください。
[https://www.indoorcorgielec.com/resources/arduinoide設定/arduino-ideライブラリのインストールとディレクトリ構成/#ボード_設定情報用ディレクトリ](https://www.indoorcorgielec.com/resources/arduinoide%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A/arduino-ide%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E6%A7%8B%E6%88%90/#%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89_%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E7%94%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA)

インストール先のフォルダやファイルを開いた状態でインストールを行うとこの状態に陥ります。
Spresense FAQ サイトにも同じことが書いてありました。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/faq_ja.html#_spresense_arduino_board_packageのインストール更新に失敗する](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/faq_ja.html#_spresense_arduino_board_package%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

一旦バージョンのフォルダを削除してインストールし直せば解決すると思います。